# Are all small probabilities incomputable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probabilistic-method

From [Nassim Nicholas Taleb.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nassim%20Nicholas%20Taleb.) in [Opacity](http://www.fooledbyrandomness.com/notebook.htm):

> I spent the last two decades explaining (mostly to finance imbeciles, but also to anyone who would listen to me) why we should not talk about small probabilities in any domain. Science cannot deal with them. It is irresponsible to talk about small probabilities and make people rely on them, except for natural systems that have been standing for 3 billion years (not manmade ones for which the probabilities are derived theoretically, such as the nuclear field for which the effective track record is only 60 years).
>
> 1) Small probabilities tend to be incomputable; the smaller the probability, the less computable. (Forget the junk about "Knightian" uncertainty, all small probabilities are incomputable). (See TBS, 2nd Ed., or Douady and Taleb, Statistical undecidability, 2011.)
>
> 2) Model error causes the underestimation of small probabilities & their contribution

Is Taleb into something? Are small probabilities incomputable?

Comment: Is the probabilistic-method tag needed? I've a feeling it's not what OP thinks it is.

Comment: Taleb likes to hear his own voice too much for all this to be digestible.

Comment: This is a kind of problem-specific question (and particularly suited to finance like situations - though others applications are clearly relevant). He is really saying something like the probability of rare events (like the GFC) cannot be computed accurately using the sample set available because it is too small to have been influenced sufficiently by small probability outcomes. The statement is simply not true as a general matter of principal (he even notes "natural systems" as a counterexample to his own claim).

Comment: "Is Taleb into something?" Definitely: self-promotion.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly the probability of winning the lottery seems to be accurately computed.  This can be quite small.

Comment: And what about things like nuclear power stations? Contrary to your lottery experiment, you can not run it experimentally an n number of times and observe how often it blows up. Here you would have to build a model.

Comment: I was reacting to the assertion that no small probability is computable.  For complex systems, where you are trying to compute the chance of failure, it is very hard.  There are always failures that you don't think of, and if the chance of the ones you do think of is small, the ones you didn't think of can dominate.  I remember claims that the space shuttle accident rate was supposed to be $10^{-5}$ or so early in the program.  Experience did not support that.